# Алгоритм Ли (волновой алгоритм по нахождению кратчайшего пути)

Tags: java, алгоритм

Нужна помощь с реализацией волнового алгоритма  по нахождению кратчайшего пути , а так же с запоминание этого пути на java.
Лабиринт выглядит  вот так :

```
0 1 1 1   0-путь по которому можно пройти
0 0 0 0   1-стена
1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0
```

На данный момент, я понял как сравнивать, если перед ним стена или нет.

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
  for (int k=0; k<=3;k++)
     if(mas[i+1][j]==0){
          должен двигаться дальше

        }
    if(mas[i-1][j]==0){
          должен двигаться дальше

        }
      if(mas[i][j+1]==0){
          должен двигаться дальше

        }
      if(mas[i][j-1]==0){
          должен двигаться дальше

        }
```

Если запустить мое сравнение, то выдаст ошибку, так как выйдет за пределы массива. Нужно сделать так, чтобы не кидала эту ошибку и объяснить, алгоритму, чтобы двигался дальше.

Comment: окружите ваш лабиринт стеной

Comment: в том то и дело, что стеной окружить нельзя

Comment: У вас `for` идет от 0 до 4х, а потом вы сравниваете с 4+1, где и вылетает. Повторю свой прошлый комментарий к другому вашему вопросу. Откройте дебагер и посмотрите, где падаете. Это быстрее, чем писать вопрос

Comment: при использовании <= для начала, сделайте length-1

Comment: Можно написать условие типа `if( i + 1 < mas.length && mas[i+1][j]==0){...}`. Тогда не будет выходить за пределы массива.